# mongoDBにおけるワイルドカード検索

Tags: mongodb

以下のようなドキュメントで、キーが"0001"のドキュメントを取得したいです。（1つ目と3つ目）
ただし、"0001"のvalueのネストの深さが一意ではありません。

```
db.collection.find( {"0001": ワイルドカード} )
```

のように指定するのかなと思っているのですが、うまくいきません。
教えてください。

```
{
    "0001": {"test1":"AAA"}
},
{
    "0002": {"test2": {"BBB": { "bbb":"ooo" } }
},
{
    "0001": {"test3": {"CCC":"ccc"} }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.find( { "0001": { $exists : true } } )
```

で期待されている結果がでますよ！

Comment: ありがとうございます！助かります！

Comment: mongoビギナーさん、状況がよく分かりませんが、スタック・オーバーフローでは自己解決した場合や自分の知識を共有する場合に[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)することを推奨しているということが参考になるかと思います :)